# Access files/ folders remotely by authentication via browser/ web

Tags: permissions, authentication, filesystems, remote-access, file-sharing

We have some requirements where we want to allow our clients/ users to download files/ folders from our file server via browser/ web.

We have a many different directories created on our file server which is mapped to different clients. Which means that, every client has its own directory on our server. We have a main (root) directory for every single client/user. Which means that, every client’s files/folder are created under their respective main directory.

The only thing we need be sure is, whenever our client make a request to access/ download file, first we need to validate their credential (username/password are stored in our SQL server DB) and then we need to allow only those folder which is mapped for specific folder. (The folder mapping is again stored in our SQL server DB)

Which means that, after applying the credential by user/clients, they can only access their directory/ files. They cannot access other’s files/ directory.

Would anybody please do let me know how would I achieve this? All the suggestions would be appreciated highly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with most webservers using their Authentication/Authorization modules. For example [Apache has a selection of modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) available for a variety of situations as does Nginx.